# TextField with borderRadius that has a connecting view

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

My issue is I'm trying to create a textField that has the functionality of having a validation message attached to the component. However, my issue is the TextField is transparent with a border + radius. But the notification message is attached to the textField seamlessly.

[image: Example of what I want]

Structure of my TextField

```
const containerStyle = {
        height: 50,
        marginVertical: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderColor: this._animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [colors.OUTER_SPACE, colors.PLATINUM]
        })
    }
    const labelStyle = {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 15,
        top: this._animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [15, 8]
        }),
        fontSize: this._animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [12, 10]
        }),
        color: this._animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [colors.OUTER_SPACE, colors.PLATINUM]
        })
    }
    const inputStyle = {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: 50,
        top: this._animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 5]
        }),
        paddingHorizontal: this._animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 15]
        })
    }

<Animated.View style={containerStyle}>
                <Animated.Text style={labelStyle}>{label}</Animated.Text>
                <Animated.View style={inputStyle}>
                    <TextInput {...props} style={styles.input} autoCorrect={false} onFocus={this.handleFocus} onBlur={this.handleBlur} />
                </Animated.View>
                <View style={styles.bottomLeft} />
                <View style={styles.bottomRight} />
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: So I need help with trying to style the bottom left & right borders so they connect to the error message view. However the background of the textField is transparent. So I can't hide the view below the text field

Comment: I want it like the image attached. so the textField has radius but the notification message attaches to the border

Answer (score 1):

You have to split up your `borderRadius: 10` on your `containerStyle` into each separate corner with:

- `borderBottomLeftRadius`: number
- `borderBottomRightRadius`: number
- `borderTopLeftRadius`: number
- `borderTopRightRadius`: number

Then make the bottom two corners `0` when there is an error.

Then add your error box last inside the container

```
<View style={styles.errorContainer}><Text>Some error</Text></View>
```

and style the `errorContainer` with the opposite corners. `0` for the two top corners, and `10` for the bottom two corners.